# How do I keep changing a color with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I wanted to keep the colors changing on a certain word. Can anyone help me? This is what I have so far:

```
var myColor = document.getElementById("color");
var colorArray = ["#ffd464", "#2980b9", "#DC143C", "#3CB371", "#DA70D6", "#9400D3"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeColor() {

    myColor.style.color('color', colorArray[colorIndex]);
    colorIndex++;
    if (colorIndex >= colorArray.length) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }

}
setInterval(changeColor, 5000);
```

Thank you!

Comment: A 'word' can't be styled directly with JavaScript (or CSS), it has to be wrapped in an element first. So, what element is it that you'd like to style?

Comment: It doesn't work? What's your question specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give a try this way, dont want to maintain an index:

```
function changeColor(){

  var color = colorArray.shift(); //get the top color from array
   colorArray.push(color); //push it to the end to cycle it
  myColor.style['color'] = color ; //syntax error here

}
setInterval( changeColor,5000 );
```

and also

```
myColor.style.color('color', colorArray[colorIndex]);
```

should be

```
 myColor.style['color'] = color ;
```

since color is a property of style attribute of the element and it is not a method.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjJZ9/)**